# Set the Http status code if it is not set

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I am trying to build a JSON string as server response with the aid of the Jackson library. If the route is not `0` I am getting tis response `{"status":201,"routes":null}` but I have problem to set the status variable to `204` in the `SDBean` class if the `routeD` is `0` I am getting in the console this output `{"status":204,"routes":[1,9,3]}` but in `POSTMAN` chrome extension the respose takes too long and I am getting this output `The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.`
I want to get the following if routeD is not 0 to get `{"status":201}` else `{"routes": {1,3,9}}`

How can I manage that with Jakson?

Receiver class:

```
@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {
        Database db = new Database();

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        double latD = data.getLatitude();
        double longD = data.getLongitude();
        double speedD = data.getSpeed();

        SDBean bean = new SDBean();
        if (routeD != 0) {
            bean.status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);
            return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

        } else {
            bean.routes = db.detectRoute(latD, longD);
            return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

        }

    }

}
```

SDBean class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SDBean {

    public int status;
    public ArrayList<Integer> routes;

    public String toJson() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;

        if(status == 0){
            this.status = 204;
        }

        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with 0 response due to you don't initialize your int value inside bean. When you try to analize your code :

```
//Inside Receiver 
return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();
```

In this line you first get value from status field from bean. It's initialize with default value of 0 ([Oracle documentation about primitive data types and default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) and next you map it toJson() where you set it's value to status response 204 in this line :

```
//Inside SDBean
if(status == 0){
    this.status = 204;
}
```

I suggest one of this resulutions:

1. Initialize variable inline:

   public int status = 204;
2. If you need some additional logic you could use static initialization block

   ```
   static {
       //additional logic here
       status = 204;
   }
   ```
3. Or simply use constructor in your case:

   ```
   public SDBean(){
       //additional logic here
       status = 204;
   }
   ```

For more info here you have documentation: [Initializing fields](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FjavaOO%2Finitial.html&ei=AuZcVbWFDcefsAGQhIGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEsq2kplE47loSFQdpbKre2-dM-og&sig2=ai2aA5TFJ-6tIgaNvJg0Qw&bvm=bv.93756505,d.bGg&cad=rja).

Also you don't add anything to your ArrayList. Try to initialize it inside your bean inline:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

or if you use jdk 1.7+ use diamond interfece instead

```
public ArrayList<Integer> routes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And now you can use it to add your data inside storeData class:

```
bean.routes.add(yourIntValue);
```

**// EDIT:**

```
package com.gmail.at.mironiuk.kacper.stack.overflow.wtf;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/data")
public class Receiver {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response storeData(Data data) {
        Database db = new Database();
        SDBean bean = new SDBean();

        String macD = data.getMac();
        int routeD = data.getRoute();
        double latD = data.getLatitude();
        double longD = data.getLongitude();
        double speedD = data.getSpeed();

        if (routeD != 0) { // here you always will have null or empty case you only set your status here
            bean.status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD); // In this if try to add sth to your list
            bean.status = 204;
            return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build(); //Expected result {"status":"204", "routes": []}
        } else { // here your List will be this whats you returns from
            bean.routes = db.detectRoute(latD, longD); // <- this function and i don't know what function returns
            return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build(); //Expected result {"status":"204", "routes": [?,?,?]}
        }
    }

}
```

I hope that I help you

Comment: I have initialized it I am not getting this error `The response status was 0` in POSTMAN anymore  but there is a strange behavior I cant see the output `{"status":204,"routes":[1,9,3]}` which is in the eclipse console in `POSTMAN` there I am getting just a small `1` but if `routeD` ist not 0 I am getting in eclipse console as well in `POSTMAN` the following `{"status":201,"routes":null}` ?

Comment: Use annotation @Produces("application/json")

Comment: And also I cannot see that you something add in your 'ArrayList'. Try to initialize 'new ArrayList<Integer>()' inline inside your bean and use 'bean.routes.add(yourValue)'

Comment: I added @Produces ... and initialized the routes ArrayList but I dont know where I should use `bean.routes.add(yourIntValue);` .As I said I just have the problem in case of `routeD=0` the response is not being sent to the client but it is being output in eclipse console I am getting this output `{"status":204,"routes":[1,9,3]}`

Comment: It is since 204 Http code status `The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content. Usually used as a response to a successful delete request..`